# How to tell Libxml2 not to parse a certain element without CDATA?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I'm trying to use Libxml2 to parse an file containing fictional program description in XML syntax. The content of specific elements might be c-code, like

```
<participant>
    <name>light</name>
    <condition>lamp=YELLOW</condition>
</participant>
```

Is it possible to tell Libxml2 parser not to parse the element starting with condition tag? 
By now, the only way seems to add CDATA tags everywhere. But I hope to be able to state that all the elements starting with certain tags shouldn't be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

libxml (and every other parser) will always parse the entire file.  It can't "not parse" the contents, because it has to know where the condition element ends - which means parsing .

Even with CDATA, it's still getting parsed, it just doesn't require escaping.  If you want to include symbols like & and < without escaping them, CDATA is the only option.